# how to use 'redirect' and 'message' on django, python

Tags: python, django

I am following the following tutorial link in order to create a page where there is login box, as well as a post form.

what im trying to accomplish here is to have only the people who are logged into the site be able to write on the post form, and submit the content.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/

If you go to the link above, Under the 'How to log a user in' section, 
it basically tells me to use

'redirect to a success page'
and 'return a disabled account error message'and 
'return an invalid login error message'

the problem here is that, It's been only a few days that I started learning about python and django, and every time such function is necessary, i mostly cannot find any source to learn those functions, or get the codes from.

I already searched on google and stackoverflow for the 'redirection' but the example i was able to get was this:

```
@app.route('/success/<int:result_id>')
def success(result_id):
 # replace this with a query from whatever database you're using
 result = get_result_from_database(result_id)
 # access the result in the tempalte, for example {{ result.name }}
 return render_template('success.html', result=result)
@app.route('/survey')
def survey():
if request.method == 'POST':
    # replace this with an insert into whatever database you're using
    result = store_result_in_database(request.args)
    return redirect(url_for('success', result_id=result.id))

# don't need to test request.method == 'GET'
return render_template('survey.html')
```

and i am yet to understand how the 'success' got in there inside 'redirect ()'

And here is the views.py that im currently working on.

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect


from.forms import PostForm
from .models import Post


from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login



def post_detail(request, id=None):
    #instance = Post.objects.get(id=1)
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)

def post_list(request):

    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            # Redirect to a success page.
        else:
            # Return a 'disabled account' error message
        else:
        # Return an 'invalid login' error message.

    form = PostForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        print (form.cleaned_data.get("title"))
        instance.save()
        # message success
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get())
    #else:
        #messages.error(request, "Not Successfully Created")
    queryset = Post.objects.all()#.order_by("-timestamp")
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "title": "List",
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_list.html", context)
    #return HttpResponse("<h1>List</h1>")

def post_update(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        # message success
        messages.success(request, "Saved")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "form":form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)


def post_delete(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    instance.delete()
    messages.success(request, "Successfully deleted")
    return redirect("posts:list")
```

is there any source i can get help regarding these kind of functions?

and also, are there any tutorials that cover how to implement the login form as well?

thank you.

Comment: What you are not understand.! Doc says redirect to success page upon successful authentication in this case if you want to show the homepage then redirect user to home page or render the success page then render it. What is wrong with that ?

Comment: @RajaSimon im getting all sorts of error, including MultiValueDictKeyError at /

Comment: Your first snippet, with `@app.route()`, seems to be for Flask, not for Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, in simplest case you need something like this.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=254)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError('invalid_login')

        return self.cleaned_data
```

Now view:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            login(request, form.get_user())

            # if you use named views you can use reverse here:
            # redirect_url = reverse('post_list')
            # Or even if you want to return back to previous url:
            # referrer = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
            # if referrer:
            #     redirect_url =  referrer.split('/', 3)[3]
            redirect_url = '/post-list/'  # it's 'success page'
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)  

    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm(request)

    return TemplateResponse(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

And now you can use `login_required` decorator for your POST views (create/update/delete), for example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def post_delete(request, id=None):
    ...
```

Simplest example for login form (template):

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Username: {{ form.username }} {{ form.username.errors }}<br> 
    Password: {{ form.password }} {{ form.password.errors }}<br>
    {{ form.errors }}<br>
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>`
```

Comment: um. okay. thanks for the kind explanation. although at this point i am yet to understand thoroughly what the code is about. but if i understand the code correctly, it requires another page that has a login field. i put the codes above inside the def post_list, so that the login fields exists inside the post_list page. how should i then be using @login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')? and also, could you care to explain how i can put the login box into the post_list as well? thanks.

Comment: What do you mean about 'login box'. Do you mean link to login page or login  form?

Comment: a login form. rather. do you think it's possible? also, im having problem due to the duplicated 'form'. i am already using 'form = PostForm(request.POST or None)' for the post form. how should i go about this..? (sorry im a novice)

Comment: In case of duplicate variables names in context, just use another name. What do you want is possible, but it's more difficult. First, you need to remove 'login_required' decorator from page where you login form will be displayed, than add login form to template.
And check if user is authenticated in you target view.